# Dynamically add value in textbox on focus of the last created dynamic textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**This code creates dynamic textboxes on focus to the last textbox with value 0 in all the textbox, I want to add dynamic values on the textbox that have been created dynamically**

```
<html>
<head>
<script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "input" ).on('focus' , addNew);

function addNew (){
    if($(this).is(':last')){
    $( this ).after( '<input type="text" value="0"/>' );
    $( "input" ).on('focus' , addNew);
    }
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

    var divBox1 = document.createElement("div");
    divBox1.style.height = "100%";
    divBox1.style.width = "200px";

    document.body.appendChild(divBox1)
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    divBox1.appendChild(input);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So.. what is the problem?

Comment: what is the source of dynamic values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4417952/keyur-shah  http://stackoverflow.com/users/3639582/shaunak-d .... I have figured it out thanks

Answer (score 0):

Few problems here:

```
<script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

should have been

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

The way you were identifying whether the targeted `input` is `last`, was not proper. Check the below updated snippet.

```js
var divBox1 = document.createElement("div");
divBox1.className = "ipHolder"; 
//adding a class to identify the container of input elements

divBox1.style.height = "100%";
divBox1.style.width = "200px";

document.body.appendChild(divBox1)
var input = document.createElement('input');
divBox1.appendChild(input);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").on('focus', addNew);

  function addNew() {
    var isLast = $(this).closest('.ipHolder').find('input').length - ($(this).index() + 1) == 0;
    //subtract the number of inputs present already with the index of clicked input 
    //within in the container for inputs and see if it is 0 which means its the last element
  
    if (isLast) {
      $(this).after('<input type="text" value="0"/>');
      $("input").on('focus', addNew);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```